# Map each input element to array in pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a (A,B) tensor, and I'm looking for a performant way to map each value from that tensor to an array to create a new tensor of size (A,B,N). Here's a functioning piece of code showing what I'm trying to do.

```
A, B, N = 3, 4, 5
my_old_tensor = torch.ones((A,B), dtype=torch.float32)
my_new_tensor = torch.zeros((A, B, N), dtype=torch.float32)
for val in range(N):
    my_new_tensor[:,:,val] = (val - my_old_tensor)/2
```

My code is currently quite slow, and I think the for-loop is the problem. Is there a more pytorch-performant way of doing this that eliminates the for-loop? I've tried something like this

```
x = torch.arange(0, N, 1, dtype=torch.float32)
my_new_tensor = (x - my_old_tensor)/2
```

but that gives "RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (5) must match the size of tensor b (4) at non-singleton dimension 1"

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unsqueeze` to [broadcast](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html) `my_old_tensor`:

```
my_new_tensor = (torch.arange(N, dtype=torch.float32) - my_old_tensor.unsqueeze(-1))/2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!